# Custom DialogBox Alert in Android is not Prompting

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, dialog, customdialog

Following is the code I have created for 2 dialog boxes: namely Date Picker and Custom Dialog Box on submit of 2 buttons namely btnselDate and btnAlertDialog.

Date Picker dialog is working properly but there is some problem with Custom Dialog Box.
My custom dialogbox displays login form for the user.

Kindly please review it and suggest appropriate suggestions for the same.

Here goes the code:

```
 public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btnselDate)
        {
            // Date Picket DialogBox

            showDialog(1);
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.btnAlertDialog)
        {
            // Alert Dialog Box

            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_activity);
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPwd);
            text.setText("Enter the Password");

            final EditText pwd=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etPwd);

            Button btnlogin=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

            btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //Login Button

                    if(pwd.getText().toString().equals("abc"))
                    {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WelcomeUser.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Password, Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Dialog Selected yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @RaghavSood I m getting force to close to error.

I don't know the problem I checked the logcat many a times but I am not able to fix the error.
Identify and let me know the error in the code if u get any ??

Comment: And the logcat shows....

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko : I have clearly mentioned that my Alert Dialog box is not promption ..

Comment: If you are getting force close then there must be Exception so for the same Stackoverflow persons always expect **Logcat output**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this

```
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_activity);
```

for a coustom layout for dialog you ll have to inflate the layout check the code here

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
        .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .create();
```

Comment: @Rushabh please check the code here to inflate a layout for an alert dialog